# Decode utf-8 in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, utf8-decode

I am following a tutorial in python 3 but I am working in python 2.7, how do I decode utf-8 for python 2.7?

The code used is:

```
data = data.readall().decode("utf-8")
```

but I get an AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'readall'
```

Comment: Your error is completely irrelevant to *encoding*, whats the type of data and what you want to achieve to with `readall()`?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that there is a difference between strings and bytes in python 3 whereas there isn't as big a difference in python 2.

The following code works in python 2: data = urllib2.urlopen(dataLink).read()